# Indesign | Delete a whole paragraph based on a s string

Tags: regex, grep, adobe-indesign

With Find/Replace or GREP I want to do the following:

Delete the whole paragraph in which there is the string "XXX".

It's not that hard I think to do but I seem to be unable to find the solution online.

Thanks!

It's for a Data Merge in InDesign where there is data sets that are included each in individual paragraphs. For those that are empty the whole paragraph should be inexistent. Since this can't be automated with Data Merge by itself, I want to at least to it with only one additional find/replace action.

This is an example line:

```
Here is random text TAB XXX m2
```

The part with "Here is random text" is the variable part. Then there is a tab and then m2.

So I need something like this with additional code where the empty spaces are:

```
     ^tXXX m2
```

Comment: Your example is to small to understand what you like to do.  Do you like to delete the whole line, if line contains `XXX`?

Comment: Okay sorry. Yes, I do.

Comment: Do you need to delete it, if it is already placed in InDesign or do you want to delete it from text files before they are placed into InDesign?

Comment: I just want to delete it from the indesign text field. I have a document with 100+ pages. All text fields have paragraphs that include the string XXX. Every paragraph that contains the string should be gone.

Comment: Found the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Here it is:

```
^.+XXX m2\r
```

Put that in the Find field in the GREP dialog in Indesign and leave the Replace field empty.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a line with `XXX`

```
sed '/XXX/d' file
```

Comment: Can you further explain? When I enter that in the GREP line it doesn't find any instance. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/vPn6yOi.jpg)

Comment: @ThomasMaier `sed` is a tool that is used on text file.  Here it delete one line with `XXX`

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I just found a working GREP expression. I'll post the answer.